# is it possible to access value bundle properties in web-flow context?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-webflow

This is a part of my web-flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
    parent="estatGeneral" start-state="a_cargar_info">

    <attribute name="caption" value="consultaDeutesHandler.filAriadna" />

    <action-state id="a_cargar_info">
        <evaluate expression="consultaDeutesHandler.primeraCarrega(flowRequestContext, usuari)"></evaluate>
        <transition on="success" to="v_formulariDeutesInici"/>
        <transition on="error" to="error"/>
    </action-state>
```

I would like to insert text from a properties bundle or backing bean into an attribute.  I tried this:

```
<attribute name="caption" value="consultaDeutesHandler.filAriadna" />
```

where `consultaDeutesHandler.filAriadna` is a function that returns a String.  Instead of the expected value I just see "consultaDeutesHandler.filAriadna" literally.

Is there a way to set the value of an attribute from a properties bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<attribute>` tag will not work since it only supports plain strings, not EL expressions.

`<set>` should do the trick:

```
<set name="flowScope.caption" value="consultaDeutesHandler.filAriadna()" />
```

(Substitute requestScope, conversationScope, etc. for flowScope as appropriate.)

You can refer to this value later in the flow xml, and from your views. For a JSF example,

```
<div>#{caption}</div>
```

will ultimately contain the value returned from `consultaDeutesHandler.filAriadna()`

Comment: this great but caption haven't got any setter, but ty for you time.

Comment: You shouldn't need a setter. This will create a flow-scoped variable called 'caption' which you can access elsewhere in the flow xml and views.

Comment: ok, so if my variable is in:RequestContext ctx   ctx.getActiveFlow().getCaption(), how i can do it? ty.

Comment: If you have a RequestContext object, you can do ctx.getFlowScope().getString("caption")