# Set Spring Webflow attribute dynamically

Tags: spring-webflow

I would like to set an attribute dynamically on a view-state like:

```
<view-state id="any" view="/some.view.xml">
    <attribute name="attr" value="#{true ? 'a' : 'b'}"/>
</view-state>
```

but the value is just taken as plain text. What ways do I have to change 'attr' based on a value in my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378014/is-it-possible-to-access-value-bundle-properties-in-web-flow-context)
The  tag will not work since it only supports plain strings, not EL expressions.

I found a solution by adding info to the variable temp in an action call and evaluating it in the flow with

```
<on-entry><set name="viewScope.attr" value="flowScope.temp eq 'X' ? 'aaaa' : 'bbbb'" /></on-entry>
```